# How to include Angular variable in Smarty single brackets?

Tags: angularjs, smarty

I am able to include Angular variable in my Smarty markup code like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="cust_id" value="{literal}{{custItem.custComp.id|number: 0}}{/literal}"/>
```

However, when I include an Angular variable inside Smarty code that is bracketed, e.g. in either of these instances, I get a syntax error:

```
  { include file='showCustomer.tpl'
  custCompObj={literal}custItem.custComp{/literal} requestId=""
  token_blacklisted=$msg.an
  token_specialAgreements=$msg.ao
  token_allconfidential=$msg.b2
  token_history=$msg.ap
  token_documents=$msg.aq
  }
```

or perhaps defining it as a variable:

```
{assign var="custComp" value="{literal}{{custItem.custComp}}{/literal}"}
```

**How can I include Angular variables in Smarty bracketed code?**

Comment: Did you find any solution regarding this?

Comment: Smarty is loaded on the backend, angularjs is loaded on the frontend, so when the backend is loaded, there are no Smarty brackets, there is nowhere to include your angular variables